# Spring-Boot @Scheduled Cron expressions to make slight delay between two tasks?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, annotations, quartz-scheduler

I am using **Spring-Boot @Scheduled Cron** for caching data retrieved from persistent storage.

I have two different tasks,

- Set result in cache
- Clear cache

Task1 will run for every 15 minutes. I have set cron like

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * *")
```

so the frequency would be

> 12:00:00
>   12:15:00
>   12:30:00

Now I want to run Task2 10 seconds before Task1

ie

> 11:59:50
>   12:14:50
>   12:29:50

I am trying this expression

```
@Scheduled(cron = "50 0/14 * * * *")
```

But it fires for every 14 minutes interval.

Can anyone please suggest me a solution to fix it?

Comment: You should read about [`Cacheable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) and stop using some strange *scheduled cache*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "50 59/15 * * * *")
```

Explanation:

```
50 59/15 * * * * = at 50 seconds, every hour at 59 minute, every 15 minutes
50 59/15 * * * * = starting at 11:59:50 for every 15 minutes.
```

Your issue is that `*/X` means "every X". So `0/14` means every 14 minutes.

[More you can read in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html):

Comment: Thanks @patrick. Temporarily I fixed it by adding @Scheduled(cron = "50 14,29,44,59 * * * *"). It is working now. I ll try yours also.

Answer (score 1):

This will run your Task2 10 seconds before Task1:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "50 14/15 * * * *")
```

It will run for example on 11:59:50, 12:14:50, 12:29:50, 12:44:50, 12:59:50...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use `fixedRate` or `fixedDelay` instead of cron expression. Your requirements aren't very sophisticated so no point in using `cron`.

- **Fixed Delay** - specifically controls the next execution time when the last execution finishes.
- **Fixed Rate** - makes Spring run the task on periodic intervals even if the last invocation may be still running - doesn’t wait for the
  completion of the previous execution.

Use example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 900000) // 15 minutes
public void taskOne() {
   ...
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 890000) // 14 minutes 50 seconds
public void taskTwo() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this method. I am using microservices architecture for my project. If more than one service instances are started at different timings @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 900000) will not work in sync in all services,. That is the reason why I switched to cron.